# Access SQL : How to retrieve all records from 2 tables (no matter they do not have record in the other table)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm creating inventory report mainly to show current qty, sum of qty that was reserved from customers and Total Qty that available .

As I used LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN but it couldn't work, so I'm thinking of UNION function but I could't make it work. Could you please help me. Thank you very much.

```
tbl_inventory
inv_id | pd_id | inv_qty_act |  inv_date | inv_note
 1     |  001  |  120        |  20-Sep-12| 
 2     |  003  |  387        |  1-Oct-12 |

tbl_reserve
res_id | cust_id | res_date | res_duedate | pd_id | res_qty | if_sent | res_note
 3     |  10     | 01-Oct-12|   17-Oct-12 |  001  |  135    |         | 
 4     |  9      | 01-Oct-12|   24-Oct-12 |  001  |  253    |         |
 5     |  22     | 01-Oct-12|   17-Oct-12 |  001  |  132    |         | 
 6     |  2      | 01-Oct-12|   24-Oct-12 |  002  |  446    |         | 


tbl_product
pd_id  | pd_name 
  001  |  des1
  002  |  des2
  003  |  des3

tbl_pdtn_startup
pdtn_st_id | pd_id | pdtn_qty_est
2         |  002  |  200
3         |  003  |  100
```

Output that I want :

```
 pd_id| pd_name| inv_qty_act|pdtn_qty_est| Sum(res_qty)| Total[(inv_qty_est) - Sum(res_qty)]
  001 | des1   |    120     |   0        |   520       |     -400 -->(120-520)
  002 | des2   |     0      |   200      |   446       |     -446 -->(0-446)
  003 | des3   |    387     |   100      |     0       |      387
```

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```sql
SELECT
    tbl_product.pd_id,
    tbl_product.pd_name,
    ( SELECT Sum(inv_qty_act) FROM tbl_inventory AS t1
      WHERE t1.pd_id=tbl_product.pd_id) AS SumOfinv_qty_act,
    ( SELECT Sum(pdtn_qty_est) FROM tbl_pdtn_startup AS t2
      WHERE t2.pd_id =tbl_product.pd_id) AS SumOfpdtn_qty_est,
    ( SELECT Sum(res_qty) FROM tbl_reserve AS t3
      WHERE t3.pd_id=tbl_product.pd_id) AS SumOfres_qty,
    IIF(ISNULL([SumOfinv_qty_act]),0,[SumOfinv_qty_act])-
      IIF(ISNULL([SumOfres_qty]),0,[SumOfres_qty]) AS Total
FROM
    tbl_product;
```

Comment: It couldn't run in ACCESS. It said it need data from pdtn_qty_est.

Comment: Did you also use MS ACCESS to test as well? Did it return only 3 rows just like my desired output?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake this statement is work. However, it's not return only 3 rows as I expected (FROM tbl_inventory, tbl_reserve). But it return all products in tbl_product instead. Do you have any idea to adjust this SQL according to my expectation? Thank you.

Comment: that SQL query outputs information for every pd_id in tbl_product.
why only three rows? Top 3? First 3? Last 3?
you need to specify a criteria that rules out the other products.

Comment: It should show only pd_id that was in either tbl_inventory or tbl_reserve. because what I want is only quantity of product that currently have stocked or quantity of product that was reserved from customer. tbl_product should be used to refer pd_name only. Thank you